# SQL Query, only one table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have units with a `startTime` and an `endTime`. Units that starts after another unit and ends before that other unit has reached the end has passed that unit. I want to calculate how many units each unit passes and how many units each unit has been passed by.

My table looks like this:

```
id; startTime; endTime 
3;  1;          2
1;  1;          8
2;  2;          3
5;  2;          9
4;  2;          5
6;  3;          4
```

The result should be something like this:

```
id; passed; passed_by
3;  0;        0
1;  0;        3
2;  1;        0
5;  0;        1
4;  1;        1
6;  3;        0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
       passed = (SELECT Count(*) 
               FROM   dbo.tablename T2 
               WHERE  T2.id <> T1.id 
                      AND T2.starttime < T1.starttime 
                      AND T2.endtime   > T1.endtime), 
       passed_by = (SELECT Count(*) 
               FROM   dbo.tablename T2 
               WHERE  T2.id <> T1.id 
                      AND T2.starttime > T1.starttime 
                      AND T2.endtime   < T1.endtime) 
FROM   dbo.tablename T1
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51740/3/0)

```
ID    PASSED    PASSED_BY
3       0          0
1       0          3
2       1          0
5       0          1
4       1          1
6       3          0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.id, 
sum (case when t1.startTime < t2.startTime and t1.endTime > t2.endTime then 1 else 0 end) as passed_by,
sum(case when t1.startTime > t2.startTime and t1.endTime < t2.endTime then 1 else 0 end) as passed
from Table1 t1
inner join Table1 t2 on t1.id <> t2.id
group by t1.id
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9b9b/12)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    id ,
    passed =
    (
       select count(rr.id) from race r
        join race rr ON r.id != rr.id
        where (r.start > rr.start) and (r.[end] < rr.[end]) and r.id = ro.id
    ) ,
    passedby =
    (
       select count(rr.id) from race r
        join race rr ON r.id != rr.id
        where (r.start < rr.start) and (r.[end] > rr.[end]) and r.id = ro.id
    )
  FROM race ro
```